# How to get value of selected item from Select2 in Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

We have an application which gets data of some products using an API and it populates the product names in a `select2` element. I want to find a desired element from Select2 and click on it. However, its all javascript and I don't seem to figure out a way out. Here is what I have done:

```
WebElement dd4 = driver.findElement(By.id("drpdwn_products"));
Select sProduct = new Select(dd4);
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-drpdwn_products-container")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("select2-search__field")).sendKeys("Shampoo");
```

It works fine till here. However, I need to trigger a click on a product item. However, it is not going through. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: can you Please add more explanation and the HTML code or screenshot, it will be easy to answer it.

Comment: @Nevermore can you post also the page source?

Comment: Please add this as a comment and not as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @petrisor.ionel It was a old project. As of now, I dont have the page source. However, if you have a question posted on Stackoverflow. I can help you with it.

Comment: Question put on hold ? I dont think the moderators program or code enough to know what I am asking ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Resolved it using

```
    driver.findElement(By.className("select2-search__field")).sendKeys("Shampoo" + Keys.ENTER);
```